# CSS transition effects between divs inside UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, css, updatepanel

I have multiple div controls in a page and each div is inside an UpdatePanel. I am trying to apply CSS transition effects between divs on button click (I switch between divs using the visibility property). How can I achieve that? transition: 2s is not working.

Comment: You should add some code or a JS Fiddle link to show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I guess.Try clicking on the links in my code snippet. Hope it helps.

```css
.buttons,
.weHide {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.weHide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <p><a href="#p1">FirstLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#p2">SecondLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#p3">ThirdLink</a></p>
</div>

<div class="weHide">
  <p id="p1">FirstPara</p>
  <p id="p2">SecondPara</p>
  <p id="p3">ThirdPara</p>
</div>
```